# CD doesn't eject

Tags: hardware, eject, optical-drive

I have a problem with ejecting a CD. It happened twice in the past few days, CD drive disappears from the list of devices in a Finder and I can't eject a CD that sits inside my laptop. I tried Disk Utility it sees the drive, but the eject option is grayed out. Typing "drutil tray eject" in Terminal also doesn't produce any effect.

Comment: I also found the shell commands `drutil eject` and `drutil tray open`, but they don't seem to be any more forceful than the other methods here.  I've not found anything short of rebooting to help me, yet.  :-(

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to try in these cases is to restart the computer and hold down your Eject key or Mouse/trackpad button while it's starting up.

If that doesn't work, try [Resetting the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US) on an Intel based mac, or a [PMU reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1431) on an older PowerPC machine, then try again.

If that fails, you'll want to bring the machine into an  Authorized Service Center if it's under warranty, or look into [less orthodox solutions](http://www.silvermac.com/2006/dvd-stuck-in-macbook-pro/) if not.

Comment: what or where is the eject key?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar solution to TrentEllingsen.  My CD drive would not relinquish this stuck CD.  Not with a terminal command or eject button or what have you.

I eventually decided to go about it manually.  First I tried using a card to leverage the CD enough so that "drutil eject" would work but after several tries it was obvious it wouldn't.  So I rubbed on some elbow grease and grabbed another card.  I slid one under the CD and the other on top.  Then, like using a pair of card-nosed pliers, I pinched tight, pulled gently, and out came the CD... with protective slip attached!  That was the last time I let my girlfriend burn anything on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a macbook that wasn't able to start up and I wanted to put in the reformatting disk in to try and fix it but had a stuck CD.

I tried holding the eject, mouse button, holding multiple buttons at the same time, tilting it.. What actually worked was a suggestion I found that using step 3 from [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2007/12/01/how-to-eject-a-stuck-cd-or-dvd-from-macbook-superdrive/)

```
I just stuck a borders gift card into the slot and then gently 
pushed it down on the rotating CD (scary sound). 
It stopped spinning and soon ejected!
```

Comment: Sounds like it worked and can see why, but this is very likely to damage the CD and the drive, I would not recommend.