# How to eject minidisc from MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

Friends, I've by mistake inserted minidisc in MacBookPro and it seems like it is stuck.

What we've already tried:

- shaking device, hoping the gravity will solve the problem
- ejecting programmatically.

I do realize that problem sound quite stupid, but if one have encountered this problem it would be nice to hear his story of salvation.

Comment: Do you mean a downsized version of a CD or a plastic cased Mini Disk? As I'm not sure an actual Mini Disc would even fit. Otherwise try these suggestions http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/949/cd-doesnt-eject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, the downfall of slot drives - getting a disc stuck in it when it dies :(

As per the comment to your question, I presume that this is a smaller CD, not an actual minidisc that is more akin to a floppy disk in a plastic case?

Oddly, some slot loading mechanisms can support these smaller discs.  For example, the Nintendo Wii is a vertical slot loader that will accept Gamecube discs that are smaller than regular CDs/DVDs.

Obviously, the MacBook won't tho.  I would recommend the use of a pair of slim "shims" that you can use to make a pair of tweezers with.  They would need to be both slim, but strong enough to get a grip with.  You may need to cover the ends if you don't want to risk scratching the disc.

Alternatively, a piece of double sided sticky tape on the end of a plastic ruler may help.  Just insert an inch (don't go too far, don't want to touch the laser with sticky stuff), and wobble it up and down a bit, see if you can get contact with the edge of the disc, then slowly pull it out.  If this is tricky, try it with the drive/laptop upside down.

Comment: A pair of lockpicks also does the trick :]

Comment: My son once inserted a SD card inside my wife's Macbook disc slot. I tried a lot of things, and eventually managed to take it out by facing the slot down and reaching the card with a small screwdriver. Took a lot of patience :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem, and turning off the laptop and gently shaking it toward the floor worked easily. No need to stick anything else into the drive.

Comment: The OP has tried this and it did not work.