# 2012 Macbook Pro won't eject CD

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

My sister bought an ancient peripheral that only has drivers for Windows.  But her Windows box has no CD drive, so I put the CD in my Macbook, made a tarball of it, put in on my web server, and downloaded it in Windows.  No problem there.

But the MBP won't eject the drive.  Keyboard button, shell command, finder control: all dismount the CD, make a lot of noise, then re-mount it.

Recently purchased refurb.  Return as warranty claim?  Or is there an alternative?  Leaving on a trip in two weeks and want to take a computer along.

Answer (score 1):

Most Macbook DVD drives have a manual release. You'll need a straightened paperclip (or something similar) to push the release. The release is at the extreme right or left edge of the DVD slot (sorry can't remember which edge it's on—it depends on the model too). Insert the clip about 1cm. It should touch a hard surface. Carefully apply some pressure and the DVD will release. If the paperclip inserts more than 1-2 cm your on the wrong edge. Also be careful to not angle the paperclip.

Comment: I’ve done that on other models, but on this model, I have been unable to find such a mechanism.  I have another drive removed from another 2012 MBP with a disc in it, and without the fuzz in the way, I can peek in and the lever is not there.

Comment: As it's out of warranty, I'd suggest checking out macfixit's take apart guidhttps://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_15%22_Unibody_Mid_2012. There are net may parts in a macbook. You could remove the dvd drive and get better access to the stuck media.

Comment: I already mentioned I had removed another drive from this model.  It's a major proctalgia removing a whole bunch of other stuff that Apple chose to put in the way.  And, since I did not say when or where I bought it, you don't know whether or not it is out of warranty.  There is _still_ a disk in the drive I removed, beause it appears that I would have to disassemble the #$%^&#$%# drive to get that CD out!

Comment: Maybe the idea from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38821/how-to-eject-minidisc-from-mbp?rq=1 will work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same laptop and I will say that I put a CD in one time and it simply never came out.  Meaning the motor the ejects the cd is simply broken.

It took a while for me to determine this was indeed the issue but I tried reinstalling the operating system and even booting into Linux/Ubuntu.  Nothing would eject the cd.

1. [I bought a new cd drive off ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X2012+macbook+pro+cd+drive.TRS0&_nkw=2012+macbook+pro+cd+drive&_sacat=0)
2. [installed it](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Optical+Drive+Replacement/5122)
3. Rebooted the Operating System.
4. Tested it.  Everything is jiffy.
5. Remove the cd from the old drive(I can't seem to find a guide to do this.)